# Using an unspecified index. Your data will be downloaded and filtered on the client

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security, geofire

How do you Retrieve this from firebase?

[image: Firebase]

Im trying create an app tracking the movement of the user but I cant get the location from the firebase. Ive Tried this code but the message below appears.

```
private void getEndLocation(){
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("User's Location");
    geoFire = new GeoFire(databaseReference);
    geoQuery = geoFire.queryAtLocation(new GeoLocation(adminCurrentLatitude,adminCurrentLongitude),10);
    geoQuery .removeAllListeners();

    geoQuery.addGeoQueryEventListener(new GeoQueryEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onKeyEntered(String key, GeoLocation location) {
            if(!userFound && requestType){
                userFound = true;
                userID = key;
                Log.d("Location", "onKeyEntered: "+userID);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onKeyExited(String key) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onKeyMoved(String key, GeoLocation location) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onGeoQueryReady() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onGeoQueryError(DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
}
```

Here is the message that I received:

> Using an unspecified index. Your data will be downloaded and filtered on the client. Consider adding '".indexOn": "g"' at User's Location to your security and Firebase Database rules for better performance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the query in your code you need to define an index in the security rules of your database like this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ...
    "User's Location": {
      ".indexOn": "g"
    }
  }
}
```

Also see the Firebase documentation on [indexing data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data) and previous [questions with the same error message](https://www.google.com/search?q=Using+an+unspecified+index.+Your+data+will+be+downloaded+and+filtered+on+the+client.+Consider+adding+%27%22.indexOn%22%3A+%22g%22%27+at+User%27s+Location+to+your+security+and+Firebase+Database+rules+for+better+performance).